# How can I pass data to an object using React Hooks and Redux

Tags: reactjs, object, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to pass data that I get from a data base to an object, using react and redux.
I cant figure out  what Im doing  wrong

This is my code

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchOrder(setOrders);
}, []);

console.log(orders);

const columnsFromBackend = {
    newOrder: {
        name: "Requested",
        items: orders
    },
    x: {
        name: "x",
        items: []
    }
};
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columnsFromBackend);

console.log(columns);
```

the result is the page renders twice, in the console it shows, fir

> orders = []

> columns = {newOrder: {…}, x: {…}}

in the second time

> orders = (39) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

> columns = {newOrder:
> items: []}

the items property inside newOrder object should have been equal to orders, but it stayed  empty

How do I pass into the items property the data of orders correclty?

just for clearance, this is the fetch function from the redux actions

```
export const fetchOrder = setOrders => dispatch => {
    fetch("/api/orders")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setOrders(data);
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_ORDER, payload: data });
        });
};
```

Thank  you and have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `columns` whenever the `orders` get updated. For that, you need to have another `useEffect` hook in your code like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setColumns(prevState => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            x: {
                ...prevState.x,
                items: orders
            }
        };
    });
}, [orders]);
```

Comment: @Nadav Yair, check this out!!

Comment: @Nadav Yair, Checkout the official docs on useEffect(https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and blog by Dan on useEffect(https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: thank you will check the information